# javascript class vs variable names

Tags: javascript, class, variables, standards

Example:

```
function car(){
  this.name = "toyota";
}



var car = new car();

console.log(car);
console.log(car instanceof car); // error
```

I guess its because the name of the variable matches the name of the "class"

ok I can change that, but "car" seems natural to me.

My question is if there are some kind of standards in javascript on how to name classes and instances of the class so they don't clash, but still be understandable?

This problem doesn't exist in php bc there variables are separated from classes so they can share the same name :|

Comment: The convention is to capitalise constructor names.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
function car(){
  this.name = "toyota";
}

var car = new car();
```

You've replaced the `car` function with the object. If you then try to do `var newCar = new car()`, you'll get a TypeError, as `car` is no longer a function and so you cannot call it.

From my experience, the most commonly used standard is similar to what you'd see in Java (See [Mozilla Developer Network Style Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style#Java_practices) for more details):

- Use lower camel case for variable and method declarations (e.g. `var name = "Michael Jordan";`)
- Use upper camel case for class definitions (e.g. `function Car() { this.name = "toyota"; }`)

You can also use Python or C style naming if you really want to, so long as you're consistent. Just keep in mind that the majority of the libraries out there seem to use Java-style naming conventions.

You may find the following JavaScript style guides helpful:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style
2. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

So in your case, you'd want to do something like this:

```
function Car() {
  this.name = "toyota";
}

var car1 = new Car();
var car2 = new Car();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually capitalize the name of classes as it follows:

```
function Car(){
  this.name='seat';
}

var car =new Car();
```

on the other hand, methods are defined as names compossed with verbs+name, where the verb is in lowercase and the name is capitalize. For example:

```
this.riseSpeed=function(){

}
```

or

```
this.restSpeed=function(){

}
```

and i usually name variables in lowercase. If the variable stores a DOM element, then i call it begining with '$', like i show below:

```
$element=document.getElementById('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, is most OO Languages (not sure if it's a formal rule), there is a convention saying that the class names should have first letter capitalized and instance names should have regular first letter.

In your case use Car for Class and car for Instance, like @Bhojendra Nepal mentioned.

Another example:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = 'Daniel';
}

var person = new Person();
```